Find the minimum value of the sum of the squares of the distances from M to the lines AB, AC and BC
The problem
Let ABCA'B'C' be a regular triangular prism with base edge $AB = 2 \sqrt{3}$
cm and height
AA' = 1 cm. If M is a point in the plane of the triangle A'B'C'
0
, then the minimum value of the sum
of the squares of the distances from M to the lines AB, AC and BC is:
my idea
the drawing

As you can see we drew $MM' \perp (ABC)$ and from M' we drew the perpendiculars $M'X \perp AB, M'Y\perp BC, M'Z \perp AC$ and by the theorem of the 3 perpendiculars we get that $MX \perp AB, MY\perp BC, MZ \perp AC$
By the theorem of Pythagoras, we realize that for $MX^2+MY^2+ MZ^2$ to be minimal, $M'X^2+M'Y^2+ M'Z^2$ must
By the inequality of means we get that the minimum happens when $M'X=M'Y=M'Z$ so basically when $MX=MY=MZ$
This means that $M'$ is the centre of the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ZXY$
I don't know what to do next! I hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

You are right. I erase this reference.

Here is a good reference ; see also here
